# Count Positive values in python [(2, 3, 4 , 5)]

Tags: python, list, count, tuples

I am new in python and I am struggling to count  the postive values, I  have this values `[(2, 3, 4 , 5)]` , and how i can count how many postive values from the given values?  and this format is list or tupple i am not sure about that. If the count is more than 0 i ahve to print "Ok"

```
a=-2,-4
b=3,5
p=[]
p.append((a,b))
if p.count() > 1:
  print("Ok")
```

Comment: Please work through any Python tutorial such that you know at least the difference between tuple and list syntax.

Comment: Also, `p` is `[((2, 4), (3, 5))]`, not `[(2, 3, 4 , 5)]`.

Comment: Also also, why do you want to *count* positive values if you just want to print OK if there's at least one?

Comment: yes @timgeb i am sorry , i am newbie

Comment: Being new is fine, but we expect a minimal level of effort for questions here, and that includes knowing the basics of the language before asking.

Comment: Just try `len(p) > 0`

Comment: you need to make a variable which keep count of positive values, now you need to loop through the list/tuple where you want to check, and then compare the vlaue if they are positive or not if positive then make that count variable increaser by 1

Comment: yes, i know that , please if you know how i can do that can you help me @timgeb

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: Is this piece of code your trial or some prerequisites? Where this append come from? This question is so unclear, it is hard to help you. The task itself is simple, but I'm not sure about what is given, what is expected, and what is you trial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list,

```
[(2,3,4,5)]
```

is a tuple inside an array. im not even sure if it will work syntax-wise.

```
a=2,4
b=3,5
p=[]
p.append((a,b))
```

im not sure about the functionality purpose of this code. Is this homework? but to answer your question, if you only want to return "Ok" if any of them is positive, you do want to iterate over every element first. since you have a tuple inside an array, you would have to do

```
list_of_numbers = p[0]
```

to get,

```
(2,3,4,5)
```

then you do this.

```
for i in list_of_numbers:
    if i > 0:
        print("ok")
        break
```

This loop will print ok and abort if any value in the list is bigger than 0. If you want to make a count, the solution is quite similar.

Also, for future questions, i would recommend you to google and research some time before asking question. There is nothing wrong about asking, but having the skill to look up answers online is quite useful in coding. I would also recommend you to rewrite your code if you dont have to have an tuple inside an array.

Hope this solved your problem.

Comment: this is OP `p` object value `[((-2, -4), (3, 5))]`, i haven't downvoted though

Comment: if you want to solve, use recursion to go through each iterable and the for no calculate if it is positive or not ie flaten the data first then count

Answer (score 0):

```
p=[2,3,4,5]
positives = 0
for number in p:
 if number>0:
  positives += 1
print_result = str(positives)
print ("We have " + print_result + " positive numbers")
```

Comment: i need to count how many opositive value i will have

Comment: I edited the code. If you need any clarifications, just ask

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32043475)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a more functional way with a lambda function.

```
scores = [1,2,3,-4,5,6]
filtered = filter(lambda score: score > 0, scores)

filtered_list = list(filtered)
count_positives = len(filtered_list)
print(count_positives) #5
```

Taken from https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-filter-list/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using numpy and its nditer method, which iteraretes over nested lists:

```
import numpy as np


a=-2,-4
b=3,5
p=[]
p.append((a,b))

count = 0

for i in np.nditer(p):
    if i > 0 :
        count = count + 1
        
print(count)

if count > 0 :
    print('OK')
```

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly. - [from review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32044167)